# Magento: Javascript error on bundled product

Tags: javascript, magento

I just created a bundled product and the price is coming out as

> Price as configured: £0.00

Even though the product list item shows the correct price.

I think I've managed to track it down to a piece of javascript in

> app/design/frontend/default/optimise/template/bundle/catalog/product/view/price.phtml

I'm getting the error  `Uncaught ReferenceError: bundle is not defined` on this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    bundle.reloadPrice();
</script>
```

There's no other reference to `bundle` in that file so I'm not sure where it's supposed to have been made.

Has anyone see this before?

Magento ver. 1.5.1.0

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem as well.

I fixed it by adding `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>` to my product\view.phtml file, likely due to what iegik mentions in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

The issue we were having was a conflict with jQuery. At some point I had added some embed code from MailChimp (which used jQuery).

Once I removed the mailchimp code. All was better

Answer (score 1):

the bundle variable should be added to html if it was not added before. This is a Product.Bundle - prototype`s model.

```
var config = <?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>,
    bundle = new Product.Bundle(config)
```

See https://gist.github.com/4203712 will help you to get know about methods like getJson, getJsonConfig...

Answer (score 0):

Realised that I had commented out some code on the view.phtml page. Things I thought that I wouldn't need but it seems that certain JS scripts or elements were missing because of that.